# Prove that $x^3 + y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Prove that $x^3 + y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

My proof: $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] = \mathbb{Q}[x][y]$. Suppose $x^3 + y^2$ is reducible. Then $x^3 + y^2 = (y + g(x))(y + h(x)) = y^2(1 + h(x) + g(x)) + g(x)h(x)$ where $g(x), h(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Comparing coefficients, $g(x) = x, h(x) = x^2$ or $g(x) = x^2, h(x) = x$ or $g(x) = x^3, h(x) = 1$ or or $g(x) = 1, h(x) = x^3$. For all cases, $1 + h(x) + g(x) \neq 1$. THis gives us a contradiction. Hence $x^3 + y^2$ is irreducible.

Comment: $(Y+g(X))(Y+h(X))= Y^2+ Y(g(X)+h(X)) + h(X)g(X) \neq Y^2(1+h(X)+g(X)) + g(X)h(X)$

Comment: @Eoin ok so then for all cases $g(x) + h(x) \neq 0$. the proof still works right? Maybe it was just typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off my comment, it is almost correct. Note $g(X)+h(X)=0$ so we must have $g(X)=-h(X)$. Also, we must have $h(X)g(X)=x^3$ so, $h(X)$ is of degree 0,1, 2, or 3. In any of these cases we have that $\deg(h)\neq \deg(g)$ so that $g(X)\neq -h(X)$. Therefore, no $g(X),h(X)$ can satisfy the conditions.